# Simple question about Fourier transformations on $L^1$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I was looking at my definition of *Fourier transformation* of a function $u \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$, and the following question came up.

**Question:** Why is it defined for $ u \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$? Why not for $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$... $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with $p \in [1,\infty]$? What is the intuition of letting $u$ be in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

Thanks for any possible explanation.

Comment: The integral defining the Fourier transform need  not exist if $f \in L^{p}$ with $p >1$.

Comment: You can extend the Fourier transform to all $L^p$ spaces. But you have to be careful because, as @KaviRamaMurthy pointed out, the usual integral definition does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and simplest reason might be that the Fourier transform $\widehat{u}$  *exists* if $u  \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ and - this should be the second reason -  has some nice properties which can be easily proven. For instance if $u \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ then $\widehat{u} \in C_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ - so it defines a continuous bounded function that vanishes at infinity.

On the other hand, the Fourier transform $\widehat{\cdot} : L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N}) \to C_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ has also 'bad' properties. For example it is not bijective  as a mapping defined on $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ to $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$.

By using the results on $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ it can be shown that for all $u \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N}) \cap L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ we have $\widehat{u} \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ with $\left\|u\right\|_{L^{2}} = \left\| \widehat{u} \right\|_{L^{2}}$. Therefore it can be extended in a unique way to an unitary operator on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$.

So in this sense the Fourier transform can be defined on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$, but have in mind that this actually is an extension of the 'original' Fourier transform on $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$.

Comment: Really nice answer, thanks!

Comment: Sir. about your 3-th line. "if $u \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ then $\hat{u}\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^N)"$... I think that this may not be true... I know that if $u \in C_c ^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ then this is true since $\hat{u} \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^N) \cap L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$, but this part by just letting be $u \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. I'm not sure if this is sufficient. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Or does it follow from $\overline{C_c ^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)} = L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

Comment: It is a popular result called "Riemann-Lebesgue" lemma. Indeed it it easy to see, that $\widehat{u}$ is a continuous bounded function for $u \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$. The "vanishes at infinity"-part needs some more care.